# how to act when meeting the same coworker(s) multiple times a day while on the way to something/someone else

Tags: communication, colleagues

I'm working in a IT-company with about 40 other people, and during my workday I happen to walk around alot to communicate with other coworkers (I hate writing E-Mails or calling them unless it's something bigger). While I'm on my way to those people, I keep meeting a lot of my other coworkers for the 2nd, 3rd, nth time a day. The first time is a simple "Hi", the next times it's just some awkward "we look at each other and don't know how to behave"-situation.

Question: How can I deal with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it belongs on IPS SE

Comment: Must be a rather large concentration of socially awkward people in your company.

Comment: Here's a handy guide - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUDH0kPdIKs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just nod or smile and walk on past.  You don't need to greet people every time, all of the time.

It's that simple.

Behaviour might be led by regional customs.  If in doubt, watch and copy what other people do.

However, in many westernized companies, just nodding and passing is fine.  Or not even nodding, or not even smiling.  As long as you don't walk into each other, you're pretty much fine.

Comment: Trying to do that, but I thought maybe I was doing something wrong. Guess I'll just stick with it

Answer (score 1):

If you're literally just passing by each other rather than actually being in their vicinity then a simple acknowledgement is all that's required, whether that's another quick "Hi" or a even a simple nod will more often then not be all that's required.